# Getting input filename in lualatex

Tags: luatex, lua, filesystem-access, jobname

As in title; I know `status.filename` gets the name of the exact file being currently compiled, but I want to know the one given as argument to lualatex. `\jobname` is also unhelpful because it may be specified to be different from input.

### Context

I am trying to parse extra arguments given to lualatex in command line; and my code currently looks something like this:

```lua
function get_args()
    arguments = {}
    reached_doc_arguments = false
    document_arg_position = -1

    for index,argument in ipairs(arg) do
        if reached_doc_arguments then
            arguments[index - document_arg_position] = argument
        elseif argument:match("%.tex$") then
            document_arg_position = index
            reached_doc_arguments = true
        end
    end
    return arguments
end
```

However, this fails in cases where the `.tex` suffix is ommited. I can't skip the first argument because options may be specified, and as mentioned, I can't use `\jobname` or `status.filename`.

Comment: with the code you show, or simply using `\jobname` you can check the location of `file` and `file.tex` so work out if `.tex` extension was defaulted.

Comment: jobname is unreliable. Maybe you can use something from the fls (recorder) file like how currfilename package does, or read the log file. That might be difficult in other cases though.